# Linux File Sorting based on subset of data

Tags: linux, sorting

OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 (Ootpa)

Following is my flat file.

```
G010XX   OLTP    PDOA210105210304210105000000000000000000000000F                        
G2019998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2019998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2019998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2019998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2019998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2019998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2029998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW-00000000000000000
G2029998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW-00000000000000001
G2029998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW000000000039213488
G2029998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW000000000000000000
G2029998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW000000000000000002
G2029998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW000000000000099357
G2039998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210095900
G2039998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210110141
G2039998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210141946
G2039998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210163210
G2039998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211141445
G2039998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211144629
G2049998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210095900
G2049998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210110141
G2049998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210141946
G2049998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210163210
G2049998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211141445
G2049998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211144629
G020000011140000000000000000000000.000
```

1. Position 1-4 is Record Type
2. Position 23-54 is Account Number
3. Position 71-88 transaction date details (only for Record Type G203 and G204)

My requirement is to

1. Eliminate duplicates on record G201 and G202 based on account number
2. Perform sorting as follows
   Level 1 - Sort By account number
   Level 2 - Sort By record type
   Level 2 - Sort by transaction date (only available in G203 and G204)

Expected Output

```
G010XX   OLTP    PDOA210105210304210105000000000000000000000000F                        
G2019998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2029998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW-00000000000000000
G2039998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210095900
G2049998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210095900
G2039998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210110141
G2049998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210110141
G2039998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210141946
G2049998199916        86010027472                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210141946
G2019998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXX860  XXUPMU TEST     
G2029998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW000000000000000000
G2039998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210163210
G2049998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201210201210163210
G2039998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211141445
G2049998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211141445
G2039998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211144629
G2049998199916        86010027524                       XXXLXXSEXXXXXW201211201211144629
G020000011140000000000000000000000.000
```

I have tried two approaches. But not getting desired output. oa is my file name.

```
[tmp] $ (
> grep "^G010" oa && \
> ( \
> grep "^G201" oa|sort -u -k 1.1,1.4 -k 1.23,1.56 && \
> grep "^G202" oa|sort -u -k 1.1,1.4 -k 1.23,1.56 && \
> grep -E "^(G203|G204|G205|G206)" oa | sort -k 1.23,1.56 -k 2.71,2.88 -k 3.1,3.4 \
> ) && \
> grep "^G020" oa
> )
G010KR   OLTP    PDOA210105210304210105000000000000000000000000F
G2019998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXX860  KRUPMU TEST
G2019998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXX860  KRUPMU TEST
G2029998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW-00000000000000000
G2029998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW000000000000000000
G2039998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210110141
G2049998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210110141
G2039998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210141946
G2049998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210141946
G2039998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210095900
G2049998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210095900
G2039998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211141445
G2049998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211141445
G2039998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210163210
G2049998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210163210
G2039998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211144629
G2049998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211144629
G020000011140000000000000000000000.000

[tmp] $ (
> grep "^G010" oa && \
> ( \
> grep "^G201" oa|sort -u -k 1.1,1.4 -k 1.23,1.56 && \
> grep "^G202" oa|sort -u -k 1.1,1.4 -k 1.23,1.56 && \
> grep -E "^(G203|G204|G205|G206)" oa | sort -k 1.23,1.56 -k 2.71,2.88 -k 3.1,3.4 \
> ) | sort -k 1.23,1.56 && \
> grep "^G020" oa
> )
G010KR   OLTP    PDOA210105210304210105000000000000000000000000F
G2019998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXX860  KRUPMU TEST
G2029998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW-00000000000000000
G2039998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210095900
G2039998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210110141
G2039998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210141946
G2049998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210095900
G2049998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210110141
G2049998199916        86010027472                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210141946
G2019998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXX860  KRUPMU TEST
G2029998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW000000000000000000
G2039998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210163210
G2039998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211141445
G2039998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211144629
G2049998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201210201210163210
G2049998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211141445
G2049998199916        86010027524                       SCBLKRSEXXXKRW201211201211144629
G020000011140000000000000000000000.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk would be an ideal candidate for this (GNU awk for array sorting):

```
awk 'NR==1 { print;next } $3 == "" { endline=$0;next } { code=substr($1,1,4);map[code][$2][$3]=$0} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";for (i in map) { for (j in map[i]) { for (k in map[i][j]) { print map[i][j][k] } } } print endline }' ootpafile
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'NR==1 { 
             print; # Print the line
             next # Skip to the next line
            } 
   $3 == "" { 
             endline=$0; # Set a variable endline to the current line where the 3rd space delimited field is empty
             next 
            } 
            { 
             code=substr($1,1,4); # Extract the first 4 characters into a variable code
             map[code][$2][$3]=$0 # Store the line in a 3 dimentional array indexed by code and other fields
             } 
         END {
              PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; # Set the ordering of the array
              for (i in map) { 
                for (j in map[i]) { 
                  for (k in map[i][j]) { 
                     print map[i][j][k] # Loop through the array and print the entries
                  } 
                 } 
               } 
               print endline # Print the end line
              }' ootpa
```